# Pillow - GIF File Size

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

The following program uses the `Pillow` package (*3.4.2*) to create a very simple *GIF* file. The file size is **11.2 KB**.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.new('P', (400, 300))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.rectangle((0, 0, img.width, img.height), fill='black')
draw.line((10, 10, img.width-10, img.height-10), fill='cyan', width=5)
del draw
img.save('Test.gif')
```

If I open this file in *Microsoft Paint* and *Save As* with a different name, the file size becomes **1.90 KB**.

Why such a big difference? Can I make `Pillow` use whatever format the *Paint* uses to get the same small size?

Comment: You can get it down to 1,094 bytes with `gifsicle -b -O2 Test.gif` I guess you could *"shell out"* to `gifsicle` with `subprocess.run()`.

Answer (score 1):

If your not making a animated GIF you can change `img.save('Test.gif')` to `img.save('Test.png')` the file size will then become **1.52KB**.

Comment: True, but I need the gif format. MS Paint png is smaller as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jpeg and optimise parameters as in here

```
img.save('Test.jpg',optimize=True,quality=95)
```